# Firewalld access from OpenVPN to ftp server

Tags: linux, openvpn, firewalld

On my router I opened port 21 to FTP and server(Alma Linux 9)works on my public adress IP. In firewalld I set below rule where access has my public IP and it works.

```bash
sudo firewall-cmd \
     --permanent \
     --zone=public \
     --add-rich-rule=\
  'rule family="ipv4" source address="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" service name="ftp" accept'
```

On my phone when I use from client OpenVPN I have access to my private network but I can't be able tob accesss to server FTP from my phone.

Comment: are you using "FTP passive mode"?

Comment: also, FTP is tiny bit… oldschool. There's really better alternatives, like SCP/SFTP, rsync.

Comment: Yes I using "FTP passive mode". I know, that exist better solution but I need it to ftp service.